# Need help running a recursive touch from Java JSP

Tags: java, unix, command, execute

Is there any way in Java to use the exec method to perform a recursive touch?

The goal is to setup a simple webpage that when reloaded will touch the dir for the site so that design can guarentee caching is no longer happening.  Any help please!!!

Here is what I have so far, and not working in my jsp:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.BufferedReader,java.io.File,java.io.FileWriter, java.io.IOException, java.io.InputStreamReader, java.util.Map" %>

<%


String s = null;
// system command to run
String cmd = "find /home/abcdefg/ -exec touch {} \\;";
// set the working directory for the OS command processor
File workDir = new File("/home/ss/public_html/ss");

try {
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, null, workDir);
int i = p.waitFor();
if (i == 0){
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
// read the output from the command
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(s);
}
}
else {
BufferedReader stdErr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
// read the output from the command
while ((s = stdErr.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(s);
}

}
}
catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(e);
}


%>
```

Comment: i think it would be better to append a random parameter ?u=12345 to urls so that the browser doesn't see the urls as cachable, and change that parameter value when ever you want 'touch functionality'    As an aside, don't put java code in a jsp. Put java code in java classes, and use el to call the approprate method.

Comment: Agree completely.  This was more of a quick utility page for my Javascript guy to have his changes pick up always without him bothering me for a restart ;-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All along the same path - I figured out the answer and it is close to what you guys posted:

<% 
    String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "cd /xx/xx/xx/xx; find . -exec touch {} \;"};
    Process  p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cmd );
%>

Thank you guys for the quick response!!

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to touch the files under `/home/abcdefg`? I could imagine that you want to touch all files under `/home/ss/public_html/ss`. If that's the case you have to change the find command:

```
String cmd = "find /home/ss/public_html/ss -exec touch {} \\;"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to separate command arguments:

```
// system command to run
String[] cmd = {"find","/home/abcdefg/","-exec","touch","{}",";"};
```